# Angular, Javascript validation skip var from return

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a simple completing form with 3 levels. is there a solution to skip(remove) a.3 from the return `only when`  a.3 = undefined ?

```
  scope.isValid = function() {
      return a.1 && a.2 && a.3;
    };


ng-disabled="!isValid()"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
scope.isValid = function() {
    return (a.3 === undefined ?  a.1 && a.2  : a.1 && a.2 && a.3);
}
```

You should learn about [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), it is an insanely powerful tool once you get the grip on it.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to reduce to normalize to

```
(a.1 && a.2 && a.3) || (a.1 && a.2),
```

or you can use array reduce to find the last non-null/empty value.

```
[a.1, a.2, a.3].reduce(function(a,b) { return b || a; }, null);
```

Comment: `&& a.3` turns `(a.1 && a.2 && a.3)` to a falsy value, which will then defer to `(a.1 && a.2)`, otherwise it will return `a.3`.

Comment: That means it is useless. If `a.3` is falsey, return `a.1 && a.2` else false. This is same as `if(a.3) { return a1 && a2 && true; } else { return a1 && a2 }`

Comment: a.3 doesn't have to be a boolean value, it can be anything.  If it is undefined or null then it turns into a false value.  Which is what the question is asking about.  If it is not null or undefined, it will return the value of a.3 which can be anything (string,number, object, etc.)

Comment: Ok, saying in other words, `true && something` ==> `something`, `false && something` ==> `false`,  `(true && something) || true` ==> `true` and `false && ...` ==> `false`.

Comment: Basically.  Its how default values are often times handled in javascript.  E.g. `userValue || default` will provide a default value if userValue isn't specified.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for the ternary operator

```
return (a.3 === undefined)?(a.1 && a.2):(a.1 && a.2 && a.3);
```

It is probably possible to not use it but i think this way is more readable.